# How can I generate an 'Email this page' URL/anchor that works the same as clicking the 'Email' icon?

Tags: joomla-3.x

In Joomla 3.x the system generates a few page-function icons for an article, including a 'Print' and an 'Email' icon.  I would like to include the 'Email' link in other places in the content of an article.  Is there an API call I can use to generate the URL/anchor that will do the same thing as clicking the icon would do?  Ie. Pop-up the 'Email this page' screen?

Just for clarity [this article](https://myportal.portalwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/demo.php?id=6942&series=330&format=text) discusses the functionality I am interested in duplicating.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple link with a window.open in the onclick event to open the mailto component in a new window, this is the html:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_mailto&view=mailto&tmpl=component&link=d737962d86ca78bb2e67d29195a13bf03d55a274" title="e-mail" onclick="window.open(this.href,'win2','width=400,height=350,menubar=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;"><span class="icon-envelope"></span> e-mail</a>
```

The problem here is the mandatory link variable in the href, it's the article link hashed by the mailto component helper, I think the only way to achieve this will be a content plugin with the ability to replace something like {email}your anchor{/email} with the above code using the mailto helper inside the plugin to hash the article link.

Comment: Thanks for the bread crumbs, @Kim!  Yes, the article mailto hash is what I'm trying to figure out how to generate.  Any ideas?

Comment: components/com_content/helpers/icon.php contains the call - find "static function email"

Answer (score 1):

1. Joomla has the option of setting it as text:
   https://docs.joomla.org/Article_email_and_print_icon_settings
2. You can do a template override of components/article/tmpl/default.php
3. Look for this code around line 42:

   ```
       <?php if ($canEdit ||  $params->get('show_print_icon') || $params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
   <ul class="actions">
   <?php if (!$this->print) : ?>
       <?php if ($params->get('show_print_icon')) : ?>
           <li class="print-icon">
           <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_popup',  $this->item, $params); ?></li><?php endif; ?><?php if ($params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
           <li class="email-icon">
           <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.email',  $this->item, $params); ?>
           </li>
       <?php endif; ?>

       <?php if ($canEdit) : ?>
           <li class="edit-icon">
           <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?>
           </li>
       <?php endif; ?>

   <?php else : ?>
       <li>
       <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_screen',  $this->item, $params); ?>
       </li>
   <?php endif; ?>

   </ul>
   ```
4. that what you need to edit:

   ```
       <?php if ($params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
       <div class="your-class">
       <?php if ($params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
       <p><?php echo JHtml::_('icon.email',  $this->item, $params); ?></p>
       <?php endif; ?>
       </div>
       <?php endif; ?>
   ```

You can put this anywhere in your content.

---

5. Another alternative would be use to an email the page module:
   http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mail-this-page

or

6. http://www.addthis.com/

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.x, from the template file, you could

```
JLoader::register('MailtoHelper', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_mailto/helpers/mailto.php');

$text      = "Email this to a friend";
$uri      = JUri::getInstance();
$base     = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'host', 'port'));
$template = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate();
$link     = $base . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->slug, $article->catid, $article->language), false);
$url      = 'index.php?option=com_mailto&tmpl=component&template=' . $template . '&link=' . MailtoHelper::addLink($link);

$status = 'width=400,height=350,top=400,left=400,menubar=yes,resizable=yes';

$attribs['title']   = JText::_('JGLOBAL_EMAIL_TITLE');
$attribs['onclick'] = "window.open(this.href,'win2','" . $status . "'); return false;";
$attribs['rel']     = 'nofollow';

$emailToLink = JHtml::_('link', JRoute::_($url), $text, $attribs);
```

The $emailToLink renders:

```
<a href="/component/mailto/?tmpl=component&amp;template=blank&amp;link=00138c314c7fbaee1454db9236c92cab1b78bd03" title="Email this link to a friend" onclick="window.open(this.href,'win2','width=400,height=350,menubar=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" rel="nofollow">Email this to a friend</a>
```

Then you need to figure out how to embed this into your article. Maybe some javascript for this.